# Clojure: cross-referenced vars, declare and compilation errors

Tags: java, clojure

In a namespace, I am defining two vars (amongst others) which are maps:

```
(declare bar)

(def foo {:is-related-to bar})

(def bar {:is-related-to foo})
```

Because `bar` is not existing when I define `foo`, I am forward-declaring it using `(declare bar)`.

There is no issues so far, everything is working as expected in the REPL.

The only thing we notice is that when I check `foo` in the REPL, I see that `bar` is unbound, which I think is to be expected with the usage of `declare`:

```
#<Unbound Unbound: #'user/bar>
```

The problem arises when I try to compile the software with `lein jar` or `lein ring war` (since it is a Ring application). The error I am getting from the compiler is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't embed object in code, maybe print-dup not defined: Unbound: #'user/bar, compiling...
```

I think this is to be expected as well since I don't think the compiler can handle unbound vars.

In any case, if all these behaviors are to be expected, why are people using forward-declaration if it can't be compiled? I am probably missing something here.

Comment: That should compile. What version of Clojure are you using? BTW, defining bar won't change the fact that foo will be mapped to Unbound, because at the time you define `foo`, `bar` is evaluated. The mapping points to the value of the var, not the var itself.

Comment: @DiegoBasch I am using 1.6.0. About your comment: exactly, so this is why I will always see `#<Unbound Unbound: #'user/bar` when evaluating `foo` since when it got first evaluated, it was unbound. Right? But in any case, because it is unbound, it is why the compiler is complaining with that Exception, isn't it?

Comment: I suspect the exception you're seeing is due to some other issue such as passing `foo` as an argument to `eval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot construct circular references in this manner. The reason it doesn't work is because `def` evaluates the form that is passed as the binding, and evaluating a symbol that resolves to a Var gets the current binding for that Var. In other words, what get put into the map `foo` is not a *reference* to the var `bar`, it's the *value* of `bar`. Redefining `bar` after the fact doesn't affect the value of `foo` - that's the point of immutability in Clojure.

Forward-declarations are typically used to allow circular dependencies between functions. The following works, because the the body of the function is not evaluated until the function is actually invoked; when the function is defined, it is indeed a reference to the Var that gets compiled.

```
 (declare bar)

 (defn foo [x y]
   (bar x (* 2 y)))

 (defn bar
   ([x] (foo x 3))
   ([x y] (+ x y)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to the Symbol bar you should use #'bar. When you use bar you have the value of bar witch is not yet defined. If you use #'bar you refer to the bar symbol witch you can evaluate when you want and will be properly defined...

```
(declare bar)

(def foo {:is-related-to #'bar})

(def bar {:is-related-to #'foo})

user=> foo
{:is-related-to #'user/bar}
user=> (:is-related-to foo)
#'user/bar
```

Comment: yes, but I really wanted to have the value of the vars, and not the reference to their symbol, so this is why I didn't use that method. However, at the light of all this information, I will check if this still stands or not. Thanks!

Comment: `#'` is a reader macro for `var`. e.g. #'bar == (var bar)  So when you do #'bar you actually get the var bound to symbol `bar` (not the symbol itself).

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, using a var like this still "works", but it's not equivalent to Alex's answer above since you end up with vars in your maps, and need to use @/deref to see their values.